# Multiple "if then/ or"

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010, worksheet-function

Not quite sure if I can do it with an if function? for the moment I am using below formula:

```
=+IF(B7<100000,"CC",IF(B7<250000,"MV, MP, PM",IF(B7<500000,"FN",IF(B7<1000000,"KH",IF(B7>1000000,"DF",FALSE)))))
```

I want to add another critera If `cell A=1` then `C=+IF(B7<100000,"CC",IF(B7<250000,"MV, MP, PM",IF(B7<500000,"FN",IF(B7<1000000,"KH",IF(B7>1000000,"DF",FALSE)))))`

If `A=2` then `C=+IF(B7<10000,"CC",IF(B7<50000,"CCL",IF(B7<500000,"FN",IF(B7<1000000,"KH",IF(B7>1000000,"DF",FALSE)))))`

Hope I was clear enough and thanks for the help

Update: just found, it was way easier than excpected :)

```
=+If(A=1,IF(B7<100000,"CC",IF(B7<250000,"MV, MP, PM",IF(B7<500000,"FN",IF(B7<1000000,"KH",IF(B7>1000000,"DF",FALSE))))),IF(B7<10000,"CC",IF(B7<50000,"CCL",IF(B7<500000,"FN",IF(B7<1000000,"KH",IF(B7>1000000,"DF",FALSE)))))
```

Ok it does only work if A is either true or false but this is my case

ps: I will try out the switch function :)

Comment: An `if` function can only be nested 7 times in the worksheet.

Comment: You could with two helper cells then check a1 and a2 after.

Comment: A nice vba switch function [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/using-the-switch-function-in-excel/)

Comment: Since Excel 2007 you can nest up to 64 functions - for this a LOOKUP formula would probably be simpler, though, e.g. `=LOOKUP(B7,{0,10000,50000,500000,1000000;"CC","CCL","FN","KH",DF})` or put those values in a two column table like Y2:Z6 and use just `=LOOKUP(B7,Y$2:Z$6)`

Comment: @barry I love it! I forget about inline arrays.

Comment: @pierre please read [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it using nested. The syntax will be as follows

```
=IF(A1=1;<first if>;IF(A1=2;<second if>;"Not in A 1 or 2"))
```

So the formula is.

```
=IF(A1=1;IF(B7<100000;"CC";IF(B7<250000;"MV, MP, PM";IF(B7<500000;"FN";IF(B7<1000000;"KH";IF(B7>1000000;"DF";FALSE)))));IF(A1=2;IF(B7<10000;"CC";IF(B7<50000;"CCL";IF(B7<500000;"FN";IF(B7<1000000;"KH";IF(B7>1000000;"DF";FALSE)))));"Not in A 1 or 2"))
```